# Python: Passing Multiple Variables Across TCP Client/Server

Tags: python, tcp, python-3.x, client-server

I'm creating a TCP client and server using Python 3.3 and I'm new to using both Python and sockets. My issue is that I need to be able to store anything passed across the connection as a separate variable for writing to various files, etc.

I'm unsure how to do this as it all seems to be one stream of data that I cannot store separately. Below is my latest piece of working code and all it does is send the data I need across the connection. Should I be trying to send all the data across as a list and de-construct it into separate variables? Can I already access them separately and I just haven't figured it out yet? Is my approach all wrong?

Server code:

```
import os
from socket import *

HOST = '' #We are the host
PORT = 29876
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
BUFFSIZE = 4096

serv =  socket( AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(ADDR,) #Create tuple with one element
serv.listen(5)
print ('listening...')

conn,addr = serv.accept()
print (conn,addr)
print ('...connected')

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")) as f:
    key = f.read()
    conn.sendall(key)
print(key)


while True:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFSIZE)
    print(data)


conn.close()
```

Client code:

```
from socket import *
import os
import socket

HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
PORT = 29876 #Must match server.py
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFFSIZE = 4096

cli = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cli.connect(ADDR,)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("gmail.com",80))
ip = ((s.getsockname()[0]))
ip = ip.encode('utf-8')
cli.send(ip)

while True:
    data = cli.recv(BUFFSIZE)
    print (data)



cli.close()
```

Comment: It *is* all one stream. You would have to separate bits out somehow. There are libraries like ZeroMQ which send separate messages over a socket - you might want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**server:**

```
from socket import *
from os.path import isfile

s = socket()
s.bind(('', 1234))
s.listen(4)
ns, na = s.accept()

loopdata = {}

i = 0
while 1:
    try:
        data = ns.recv(8192)
    except:
        break

    for line data.split('\n'):
        if line == 'version':
            print na[0] + ' requested a version'
            ns.send('1.0\n')
        elif line == 'key':
            print na[0] + ' is requesting a key'
            if isfile(na[0] + '.key'):
                with open(na[0] + '.key') as f:
                    ns.send(f.read())
            else:
                ns.send('Missing key file!\n')
        loopdata[i] = line

        #ns.send('OK\n')
        i += 1
ns.close()
s.close()

print loopdata # <- Print all the lines
```

**client:**

```
from socket import *
s = socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1234))

s.send('version\n')
print 'Client got:', s.recv(8192)
s.close()
```

I'm not sure as to what you want to save/store/respond to,
You mentioned something about a key in your code and in your client code you created multiple sockets but only really used one.. and that was for printing whatever the server was sednding?

Begin clean, try to figure out things before mixing it all up.
And state a clear goal that you want to achieve with your code? what do you want to send? and when sending X, what do you want the server to respond?

**Tactics:**

```
 1. You want to define a protocol,
    1.1 Command separator
    1.2 Command structure (ex: command:parameter:data\n)
    1.3 sates (ex login state etc etc..)
```

After you know what you want to do, ex file share:

```
c->s: get:file:/root/storage/file.txt\n
c<-s: file:content\n
c<-s: <file data>\n\n
c<-s: file:close\n
c->s: file:recieved
```

For instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to work from this and report back on how it goes. 
I would be storing pretty much everything passed along the stream as a separate variable. Specifically, the key would be a variable which is to be written to a file, the IP would be another. Another would be a software version number which is read, passed and then compared on the opposite side of the stream which will trigger a separate shell script if the software is out of date.

Comment: I added a short example of how to respond to a client asking for `version` or a `keyfile` :) Gl building your server!

Comment: While this was useful to me it was not exactly what U needed. I decided to go a different way with this as it is only a small script. I decided upon opening a separate socket and data stream for each variable and writing and reading files to store each one.